# Heroku-toolbelt installation give error in my mac OS X

Tags: ruby-on-rails, node.js, macos, heroku, heroku-toolbelt

After installation heroku toolbelt in my mac OS X terminal when I gave herkou --version or any heroku command it's shows me

```
$ heroku --version
/usr/local/heroku/lib/heroku/jsplugin.rb:108: warning: Insecure world writable dir /usr/local in PATH, mode 040777
heroku-cli: Adding dependencies...
 ▸    Get https://cli-assets.heroku.com/node/v5.7.0/node-v5.7.0-darwin-x64.tar.gz: dial tcp: lookup cli-assets.heroku.com on 192.168.192.10:53: cannot unmarshal DNS message
done
heroku-cli: Installing core plugins...
 ▸    

 ▸    fork/exec bin/node: no such file or directory
heroku-cli: Installing core plugins (retrying)...
 ▸    Error installing package. 
 ▸    
 ▸    Try running again with GODE_DEBUG=info to see more output.
```

For Sample I gave my terminal image.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Probably you need to fix the /usr/local directory permission. Not sure you're on which OS X version. Please try to use Disk Utility to fix the permission.

https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201560

I think it should be 755 instead 777 (which is world-writeable)

Hopes that help!

Comment: Thank you Brother for your dynamic solution. My OS X version is OS X EI captain so I was follow this instruction To disable System Integrity Protection :

1. Boot into the Recovery HD by restarting whilst holding ⌘R.
2. Open Terminal (from the Utilities menu).
3. Run the following command in Terminal:
    csrutil disable
4. Restart.
And change permission to in /usr folder. Finally Now I am using heroku cmnd properly.

Comment: Thanks @Mahsin. I have the same problem. I haven't tried your solution yet, but it's surprising that's what it takes to get the Toolbelt to install correctly.

Comment: You are welcome @danyim you can try this solution if you face this problem. If need any further information feel free to ask.